# Webmaster Tools show the "Total Indexed" number to be zero after moving it to a new domain

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, googlebot

I recently switched my domain from [yannbane.blogspot.com](http://www.yannbane.com) to [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com), and added my new domain to my Webmaster Tools account. After a few days, I went there and checked the data, and I was a bit worried when I saw this:

[image]

How can I interpret this? Is Google really not indexing my site at all? I'm afraid that's the case, because when I google for it, only my old blogspot domain shows up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your indexed pages are probably still under your old domain: `yannbane.blogspot.com`

Normally it would be a matter of issuing a permanent redirect (301) from the old domain to the new and wait for Google (and everyone else) to update their links. This could well take a lot longer than a few days, so it's a case of being patient. It is important that the redirect stays in place for as long as possible (at least a few months, or *forever* if you can!).

This is *sort of* what's happening with your domain, however, there is a slight anomaly:

```
yannbane.blogspot.com   --> yannbane.blogspot.co.uk (302 temporary redirect) ?
yannbane.blogspot.co.uk --> www.yannbane.com (301 permanent redirect)
```

There are 2 redirects. Why is the first redirect a 302 (temporary redirect) and not a 301? Why is the first redirect even there at all? However, I suspect it will be OK and Google will see that your new (final) domain is the one to be indexed, but I'm not 100% sure - so please comment.

**EDIT:** As noted in comments, the middle (temporary) redirect would seem to be dependent on the users location (probably returning what it thinks is the nearest). I'm in the UK, hence .co.uk. If you try the tool at web-sniffer.net (based in Germany), it shows a temporary redirect to `yannbane.blogspot.de` as the first hop.

Comment: Hey! Up till now, my old domain ([yannbane.blogspot.com](http://www.yannbane.com)) did not redirect at all! Now, I don't even know *anything* about those .co.uk domains, I suppose it was set up by Google. Could you please tell how did you find out about those redirects so I can look it up myself?

Comment: I went here: http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/, and typed in "yannbane.blogspot.com", and there is only one redirect, to my site. None of those inbetween domains were shown, and no temporary redirects!

Comment: I used the Chrome Developer Tools (built in to browser - F12) - this shows all the network traffic. The tool you used (internetofficer.com) seems to only show the final hop. I've just noticed that the middle (temporary) redirect is dependent on your location (and probably returns what it thinks is the nearest). I'm in the UK, hence .co.uk. If you try the tool at web-sniffer.net (based in Germany), it shows a redirect to yannbane.blogspot.de - I'm 99.9% sure this is perfectly OK.